# Office 365 REST API to create contacts using CURL gets HTTPCode 400 Bad Request

Tags: api, rest, curl, contacts, office365

I am testing Office 365 REST API using CURL following this link:

[Contacts REST API in Office 365 APIs Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn792115(v=office.15).aspx)

I can obtain correctly one contact using curl command in Windows like this:

```
curl --no-sessionid --insecure --basic --user "user@domain.com:password" -H "Accept: application/json" "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Contacts?$orderby=DisplayName+asc&$top=1"
```

And following documentation on this link if I try to create one contact using CURL with minimum required options for testing:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"@odata.type\": \"#Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Contact\",\"GivenName\": \"TestContact\",\"EmailAddress1\": \"test@test.com\",\"BusinessPhone1\": \"123-456-7890\"}" https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts --header "Content-Type:application/json" --insecure --verbose --user "user@domain.com:password"
```

I receive following error:

```
* About to connect() to outlook.office365.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 157.56.250.178...
* connected
* Connected to outlook.office365.com (157.56.250.178) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
...
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
...
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user@domain.com'
> POST /ews/odata/Me/Contacts HTTP/1.1
...
> Content-Length: 157
>
* upload completely sent off: 157 out of 157 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
...
< Content-Length: 82
<
{"error":{"code":"ErrorInvalidRequest","message":"Cannot read the request body."}}* Connection #0 to host outlook.office365.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

I have searched the internet and in stackoverflow but similar questions have no answer I'm looking for.

How could I create on contact using CURL?, I have tested it on Linux too but have the same results.

Comment: Sorry, hit <Enter> by mistake.  I am able to repro this issue using Fiddler.  So this doesn't appear to be a CURL-specific issue.  One reason for this is there are some breaking changes currently being deployed to the service, and the OData.Type has changed and Email addresses, Phone numbers etc. are now collections.  Version support is currently being rolled out, and once it is in place, non-backwards compatible changes won't be an issue going forward.  Let me construct a working request, and then post an answer.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following request works when I try it from Fiddler.  Can you please try this out using CURL?

```
POST https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic <XXXX>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "GivenName" : "John",
  "EmailAddresses" : [ 
    { "Address": "John@contoso.com", "Name" : "John" }
  ],
  "BusinessPhones" : [
    "123-456-7890"
  ]
}
```

I made a few changes to your request.  You don't need to specify the OData.type as we infer that you are adding a Contact because you are sending a POST to Contacts collection.  We need to fix our documentation as it lists the entity type as required.  We have updated our namespace to Microsoft.OutlookServices and hence the type definitions have changed.  To make the API easier to use, we have replaced EmailAddress1, EmailAddress2 etc. with a collection of EmailAddresses.  Similarly, we have also changed BusinessPhones, HomePhones etc. to collections as well.

As I just explained in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399352/cant-create-new-events-with-office-365-api), the issues you are seeing are from some [changes being rolled out to our preview APIs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fc135ae-f8f9-4b4d-b50b-f00a2bd79a30/office-365-rest-api-mail-calendar-contacts-update?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment) and our documentation is in the process of being updated.  The current set of changes include versioning support, and this won't be an issue going forward.

Please let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: It worked perfect, i answer to this question to indicate CURL command used.

Answer (score 0):

Using following CURL command worked perfect:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"GivenName\":\"John\",\"EmailAddresses\":[{\"Address\":\"John@contoso.com\",\"Name\":\"John\"}],\"BusinessPhones\":[\"123-456-7890\"]}" https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts --header "Content-Type:application/json" --insecure --verbose --user "user@domain.com:password"
```

Now we can export contacts (this is not allowed from OWA) and import it using simple utilities like curl.

Thanks for your help Venkat.

Answer (score 0):

Your original post showed the following namespace:
Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Contact

That has been changed to:
Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices.Contact

Since the namespace was wrong, it couldn't read the request body.