# ErrorInvalidRequest while using post request in office365

Tags: api, rest, office365, rest-client

using restClient, I am trying to add a new event.

```
url: https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Events
```

My json for the creation of an event is

```
{"IsAllDay":false,"Subject":"TEST","Start":"2015-02-20T07:32:39Z","End":"2015-02-20T08:32:39Z","Body":{"ContentType":"HTML","Content":"TEST JRA ? TU VOIS ?"}}
```

The response I get is

```
{
   "error":
   {
       "code": "ErrorInvalidRequest",
       "message": "Cannot read the request body."
   }
}
```

What is wrong with my json and how do I solve this error ?

Comment: Please do you have the full example of your code ? I am trying to create an event using Office365 Api and I got a problem .. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your Content-Type is `"application/json"`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make the request work.  See below for sample request and response.

```
POST https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Me/Events HTTP/1.1
Authorization: <Snipped>
Content-Type: Application/Json

{
   "IsAllDay":false,
   "Subject":"TEST",
   "Start":"2015-02-20T07:32:39Z",
   "End":"2015-02-20T08:32:39Z",
   "Body":{
      "ContentType":"HTML",
      "Content":"TEST JRA ? TU VOIS ?"
    }
}
```